# googlesheet - Call month API in query statement not work as expected

Tags: google-sheets

To summarize each month's balance, I try to call month API in query statement. but sounds like the month API always return (month - 1) but not month.

Example data:

```
| Type    | TransDate  |  Amount |
|---------+------------+---------|
| Sale    | 08/13/2017 |  -40.97 |
| Return  | 08/10/2017 |  127.48 |
| Payment | 08/07/2017 | 2194.45 |
| Sale    | 08/07/2017 | -100.97 |
| Sale    | 08/06/2017 | -143.44 |
| Sale    | 07/02/2017 | -143.44 |
| Sale    | 07/03/2017 |   -7.55 |
| Sale    | 08/04/2017 |   -8.03 |
```

I use below formula:

```
=query(A:C,"select MONTH(B),sum(C) where A = 'Sale' or A = 'Return' group by MONTH(B) label MONTH(B) 'Month',sum(C) 'Total'")
```

The result table:

```
| Month |   Total |
|-------+---------|
|     6 | -150.99 |
|     7 | -165.93 |
```

The month should be 7 and 8, but actually it return 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) says:

> Returns the zero-based month value from a date or datetime value. For example: month(date "2009-02-05") returns 1. Note: the months are 0-based, so the function returns 0 for January, 1 for February, etc.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not the save as ```=MONTH(B2)```, this formula works as expected. But the when call it from query API, it's another version. How can I fix my case then!

Answer (score 0):

As @puts said, the index is start from 0, fix that with a offset:

```
=query(A:E,"select MONTH(B)+1,sum(E) where A = 'Sale' or A = 'Return' group by MONTH(B) label MONTH(B)+1 'Month',sum(E) 'Total'")
```